# Can't use Java 21.0.1 and Gradle 8.1.1 to import Gradle project android

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I am currently working on a Flutter repository and whenever I start the repository it gives me an
error:
`Can't use Java 21.0.1 and Gradle 8.1.1 to import Gradle project android.`

How should I fix this thing?

[image]

Since the program was running I didn't try anything new.

This is the error that I get when I open the repo in my VSC
[image: VSC extension's notification]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [upgrade](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html) your Gradle version to be able to use Java 21.

As stated in Gradle's [Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java), you need Gradle 8.4 to compile/test with Java 21, and Gradle 8.5 to run Gradle itself on Java 21.

Comment: how should I upgrade the gradle version? Do you know any CLI commands to do that?

Comment: From your screenshots it looks like you're using the Gradle Wrapper (`gradlew` command). With that it's easy to upgrade from the command line; `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.5`. For more info, see the first hyperlink in my original answer.